# error: no known class method for selector 'setScreenName:screenClass:'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Hi im trying to build my app for flutter and the compiler returns back an error:

```
Command MergeSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code
/Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_analytics-7.1.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAnalyticsPlugin.m:49:19: error: no known class method for selector 'setScreenName:screenClass:'
    [FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverride];
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have tried to google as much as i can but i dont know why else it is not working
my flutter is in the latest version on channel stable: 2.2.3

I have tried
-flutter clean
-pod update
-pod install --repo-update
-pod install
-sudo gem install cocoapods

Please help out i will try to supply any other information required. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

**If same error is occurring in react-native then**
in RNFirebaseAnalytics.m file, update following line of code:

```
[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverriew];
```

to

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:kFIREventScreenView parameters: @{kFIRParameterScreenName: screenName}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Upgrade firebase_analytics to latest version
flutter clean
remove Podfile.lock
pod update
flutter run
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in RNFirebaseAnalytics.m file, update the following line of code:

[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:screenName screenClass:screenClassOverriew];

to :-

[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName :kFIREventScreenView parameters: @{kFIREventScreenView: screenName}];

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).